# How to include message in response object with PHP & javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, response, fetch

I'm trying to use the new Fetch API for a contact form, which ought to submit the form and get back a response that I can display to the user via `appendChild`.

Unfortunately, I'm failing to get a string returned and displayed.  I get a 200 status code in the response object, but not my desired message.

```
var form = document.getElementById('ajax-contact'),
    formaction = form.getAttribute('action'),
    formMessages = document.getElementById( 'form-messages' );

form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    fetch(formaction, {
        method: 'post',
        body: new FormData(form)
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        formMessages.classList.remove('error');
        formMessages.classList.add('success');

        var content = document.createTextNode(response);
        formMessages.appendChild(content);

    })
});
```

My PHP form handler response section:

```
if ($recipient) {
    http_response_code(200);
    echo "Message has been sent.";
} else {
    http_response_code(500);
    echo "Something went wrong.";
}
```

I don't know what I'm missing here.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: how do you initialize `$recipient` at the server request handler?

Comment: Abdo, that's not relevant.  The if statement works, and `$recipient` is handled right.  The problem is the passing of the message that accompanies the response code.

Comment: If you log the response in your console can you see the text?

Comment: Damien, no.  The proper response is there ( 200 or 500 ), but the text is not.

Comment: try setting the response status and content type, `header("HTTP/1.1 200");header("Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8"); echo 'what ever';`

Comment: That does not return the echo text.